# How to validate mat input text field inside a mat table in angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a mat table in where Im getting values from backend and displaying. Now Im trying to add a new typeable field "cmnts", where it should be a text field and have validations. My issue here is validation is applying to every row & whatever text im entering in the first row , that is appearing in all the rows. Is my form control name should be unique for each row. In that case how should i use in ts file. Could you please suggest?

My html code is like below:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="" matSort > 
        <tbody>
        <th><td>...</td></th>
         <ng-container matColumnDef="cmts">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Comments    
        </th>
        <form [formGroup]="commentsForm" >
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <span *ngIf="element?.id=='321'">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput id="cmnts" formControlName="cmnts" required>
                <mat-error *ngIf="submitted || h.cmnts.errors || h.cmnts.touched">
                    <span *ngIf="h.cmnts.errors?.required">cmnts is Required</span>
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="submitted || h.cmnts.errors">
                    <span *ngIf="h.cmnts.errors?.minlength"> Minimum length should be 10</span>
                </mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="submitted || h.cmnts.errors">
                    <span *ngIf="h.cmnts.errors?.maxlength"> Maximum length should be 30 </span>
                </mat-error> 
            </mat-form-field>     
            </span>
        </td>  
        </form>      
       </ng-container>
```

My Ts file :

```
 commentsForm: FormGroup;

 this.commentsForm = this.fb.group({
    cmnts:  ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(40)]],
 })

 get h() { return this.commentsForm.controls; }
```

I have tried using formArray as below also. still unable to set validations separtely for each row. Please suggest.
//Updated

```
     <form [formGroup]="CmntsForm" >
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let rowIndex = index">
      <span *ngIf="element?.sts=='A'">
       <mat-form-field> 
         <input matInput id="cmnts" formControlName="cmnts" required>
       </mat-form-field>
       </span>
      </td>
```

ts:

```
this.CmntsForm = this.fb.group({
        cmnts: this.fb.array( ['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(30)]])

})

get cmnts(){
    return this.CmntsForm.controls["cmnts"] as FormArray;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure form array of form group with own validation rules for each row. Here is an example with the latest version of angular hope it helps.

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="commentsForm">
  <table formArrayName="usercomments" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.name}} </td>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="comment">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Comment </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item; let rowIndex=index">
      <div [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input
              placeholder="Enter comment"
              formControlName="comment"
              matInput
            />
            <mat-error *ngIf="commentFormArray.controls[rowIndex].get('comment')?.hasError('required')">
              Comment is required.
            </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
      </div> 
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
  <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="commentsForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

TS:

```
export interface UserComment {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  comment: string;
}

export class UserCommentsComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'comment'];
  dataSource: UserComment[]  = [
     { id: 1, name: 'John', comment: ''},
    { id: 2, name: 'Abram', comment: ''}
  ];

 commentsForm: FormGroup;
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
 ngOnInit() {
    this.commentsForm = this.fb.group({
     usercomments: this.fb.array(this.loadUserComment(this.dataSource))
    });
 }

 get commentFormArray() : FormArray {
  return this.commentsForm.controls["usercomments"] as FormArray
 }
 private loadUserComment(comments: UserComment[]): FormGroup [] {
  return comments.map((item: UserComment) => 
    this.createCommentFormGroup(item));
 }

 private createCommentFormGroup(item: UserComment) : FormGroup{
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(item.name),
      comment: new FormControl(item.comment, [Validators.required])})
 }
}
```